Equivalent definitions of ultrafilters
Let $X$ be a set. We call $\mathscr{F} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ a filter if it satisfies the following conditions:

$X \in \mathscr{F}$ and $\emptyset \not\in \mathscr{F}$

$A, B \in \mathscr{F} \Longrightarrow A \cap B \in \mathscr{F}$

$A \in \mathscr{F}, A \subseteq B \subseteq X \Longrightarrow B \in \mathscr{F}$


We call $\mathscr{F}$ an ultrafilter if it satisfies any of the following equivalent conditions:

If $\mathscr{G}$ is a filter and $\mathscr{F} \subseteq \mathscr{G}$, then $\mathscr{F} = \mathscr{G}$

If $A \subseteq X$, then $A \in \mathscr{F}$ or $X \setminus A \in \mathscr{F}$

If $A, B \subseteq X$ with $A \cup B = X$, then $A \in \mathscr{F}$ or $B \in \mathscr{F}$

If $A, B \subseteq X$ and $C \in \mathscr{F}$ with $A \cup B = C$, then $A \in \mathscr{F}$ or $B \in \mathscr{F}$

If $A \subseteq X$ and for every $B \in \mathscr{F}$, $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$, then $A \in \mathscr{F}$


Are there other useful characterizations of ultrafilters? I'd like to have a list that is as big as possible.

You can pretty much double the conditions you have already written using the fact that the dual of a filter is and ideal. However it's not all that insightful.

In 3. and 4. it should be "or" instead of "either or" (e.g.,  $A=B=X$).

@Ulli Thanks, fixed

In this long answer, I mention two closely related characterizations of ultrafilters, one coming from category theory (sections I and II), the other from nonstandard analysis (section III).

Ultrafilters on the set $X$ correspond to natural transformations from the functor $Hom(X,-) : \mathrm{FinSet} \rightarrow \mathrm{Set}$ to the inclusion functor $\iota(-): \mathrm{FinSet} \rightarrow \mathrm{Set}$.

Ultrafilters on the set $X$ correspond to evaluation functionals sending functions $f: X \rightarrow Y$ to the value $~^*f(\omega) \in Y$ where $Y$ is an arbitrary finite set and $\omega$ belongs to the nonstandard analytic $~^*$-extension $~^*X$ of the set $X$.



I. Consider the set $X$ as an object in the category of sets. This object gives rise to a covariant hom functor $Hom(X,-) : \mathrm{Set} \rightarrow \mathrm{Set}$ which sends

each object $Y$ to the set $Hom(X,Y)$ consisting of all functions $X \rightarrow Y$;
each morphism $f: Y_1 \rightarrow Y_2$ to the morphism $(f \circ -): Hom(X,Y_1) \rightarrow Hom(X,Y_2)$.

What is a natural transformation from the functor $Hom(X,-)$ to the identity functor $Id:\mathrm{Set}\rightarrow\mathrm{Set}$? By the Yoneda lemma, these natural transformations correspond exactly to elements of the set $X$. More concretely, for each such natural transformation $\nu$, we can find an element $x\in X$ so that for any set $Y$, the $Y$-component of $\nu$ is the evaluation function
$$ \nu_Y: Hom(X,Y) \rightarrow Y\\
  \nu_Y(f) = f(x).\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$
We can recover this element $x \in X$ by evaluating $\nu_X(\mathrm{id}_X) = \mathrm{id}_X(x) = x$.
II. Intuitively, one could summarize the previous section as follows. A function $Hom(X,Y) \rightarrow Y$ that works for any $Y$ (or is parametric in $Y$) is precisely an evaluation map at some element $x$.
This is in strict contrast with functions $Hom(X,Y) \rightarrow Y$ that only have to work for a specific $Y$. For example, by Cantor's theorem, there are a great many functions from $Hom(\mathbb{N},\{0,1\})$ to $\{0,1\}$, strictly more than the number of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, and much more than the number of elements of $\mathbb{N}$. Consequently, most such functions are not evaluation maps.
Ultrafilters lie between these two extremes. In the first scenario, we studied maps $Hom(X,Y) \rightarrow Y$ that worked uniformly on every $Y$. In the second scenario, we studied maps that were defined only for one specific $Y$. But what about maps that work uniformly across a large number of sets, but not all of them? For example, what about maps $Hom(X,Y) \rightarrow Y$ that work the same way for each finite set $Y$?
More formally, consider the usual inclusion functor $\iota(-): \mathrm{FinSet} \rightarrow \mathrm{Set}$, and the hom functor $Hom(X,\iota(-)): \mathrm{FinSet} \rightarrow \mathrm{Set}$. Can we characterize the natural transformations between $Hom(X,\iota(-))$ and $\iota(-)$?
As before, we still have evaluation maps $f \mapsto f(x)$ where $x \in X$. If $X$ is a finite set, that covers everything. The proof mirrors the Yoneda lemma: such a natural transformation $\nu$ is completely determined by $\nu_X(\mathrm{id}_X)$.
But this Yoneda-style argument fails for infinite sets $X$, and for good reason! Given an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\mathcal{P}(X)$, and a finite set $Y=\{y_1,\dots,y_n\}$, we have that for each $f \in Hom(X,\iota(Y))$, exactly one of the sets $\{x \in X \:|\: f(x) = y_1\}$, $\{x \in X \:|\: f(x) = y_2\}$, $\dots$, $\{x \in X \:|\: f(x) = y_n\}$ belongs to $\mathcal{U}$. Using this fact, define a transformation $u$ from $Hom(X,\iota(-))$ to $\iota(-)$ where $u_Y(f)$ sends $f: X \rightarrow Y$ to the unique value $y \in Y$ for which the set $\{x \in X \:|\: f(x) = y\}$ belongs to the ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$. The naturality of this transformation is easy to check.
This correspondence is exact: the ultrafilters on $X$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the natural transformations from $Hom(X,\iota(-))$ to $\iota(-)$. The evaluation maps correspond to principal ultrafilters; the extraneous natural transformations come from nonprincipal ultrafilters. The fact that a finite set never admits nonprincipal ultrafilters comes from the Yoneda lemma.
The first to characterize ultrafilters this way were Kennison and Gildenhuys. I recommend Leinster's artile on codensity and the ultrafilter monad for a detailed treatment.
III. The results of the previous section tell us that principal ultrafilters on $X$ arise from evaluation maps $f \mapsto f(x)$. How should we understand nonprincipal ultrafilters? Well, nonstandard analysis allows us to view all ultrafilters, including nonprincipal ones, as arising from evaluation maps over certain "ideal"/"imaginary"/"nonstandard" elements of the set $X$! I'll elude most technical details here: they can be found in the article of Cherlin and Hirschfield (the version using model theory / superstructures) or on pp43-45 of my PhD thesis' introduction (the version using Internal Set Theory; I think the latter setting works better for these kinds of results, since there's no need to worry about the extensions taken and no need to study technical saturation conditions; YMMV).
The basic idea is the following. Given a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$, we can consider its nonstandard $~^*$-extension $~^*f: ~^*X \rightarrow ~^*Y$. When $X$ is infinite, the extended domain $~^*X \supset X$ contains a great many nonstandard elements: for example, the hyperreals arise as the extension $~^*\mathbb{R}$ of the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, and $~^*\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{R}$ contains infinitesimal and infinite quantities of nonstandard analysis. However, if a set is finite, we always have $~^*Y = Y$.
This allows us to obtain a transformation $\nu_Y$ from $Hom(X,\iota(Y))$ to $\iota(Y)$ as follows. Fix an element $\omega \in ~^*X \setminus X$. Given $f \in Hom(X, \iota(Y))$, consider the $~^*$-extension $~^*f : ~^*X \rightarrow Y$. Set $\nu_Y(f) = ~^*f(\omega)$. We can see that this construction is uniform in $Y$. After taking care of some technical details, we get that every ultrafilter on a set $X$ arises as a standard "shadow" of evaluation at some element of a $~^*$-extension: principal ultrafilters come from elements of $X$, whereas nonprincipal ultrafilters come from nonstandard elements of $~^*X \setminus X$.
edit: You can identify $\mathcal{P}(X)$ with the function space $X \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. We get that $\nu_{\{0,1\}}$ assigns to every subset of $X$ the value $1$ if $\omega \in ~^*X$ and $0$ otherwise. As Mikhail Katz mentions below, the collection $\{A \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \:|\: \nu_{\{0,1\}} (A) = 1 \}$ is then an ultrafilter. One should keep in mind that the element $\omega$ is not uniquely determined by $\nu$: there might be two different nonstandard $\omega_1, \omega_2$ that generate the same (standard) nonprincipal ultrafilter under this construction.

Since this answer is lengthy, there will be typos and small errors. I appreciate it if people point them out, and will attend to them tomorrow.

You might want to add the following simple-minded comment.  Let $x$ be any nonstandard hyperreal.  Let $n$ be its integer part.  Then $x-n$ is finite (i.e., limited).  Then the difference $\epsilon=x-n-\text{st}(x-n)$ is a nonzero infinitesimal.  Therefore $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ is infinite (i.e., unlimited).  Let $H$ be the integer part of $\frac1{\epsilon}$.  Then one obtains a nonprincipal ultrafilter ${A\subseteq\mathbb N: H\in {}^\ast!! A}$.

@MikhailKatz: Thanks! Great idea. I'll add a paragraph tomorrow with this example and a brief explanation that with $Y={0,1}$, the evaluation corresponds to set membership.

I first heard this idea from Shelah years ago.

I should say that if $x$ is a nonstandard integer to begin with, we construct the ultrafilter directly with the formula ${A\subseteq\mathbb N : x\in{}^\ast!!A}$.  If not, we carry out the construction I outlined with nonzero $\epsilon$.

Here are two interrelated perspectives, both of which come from the theory of Boolean algebras, which the structures $(\mathcal{P}(X), \cap,\cup, X, \emptyset, -) $ are instances of.


Given a set $X$, ultrafilters of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ are in 1-1 correspondence with Boolean algebra homomorphisms $f$ from $(\mathcal{P}(X), \cap,\cup, X, \emptyset, -) $ onto the $\{\{\emptyset\}, \emptyset\}$.

In particular, given a boolean algebra homomorphism $f:\mathcal{P}(X)\to \{\{\emptyset\}, \emptyset\}$, we have that $f^{-1}(\{\emptyset\})$ is an ultrafilter on $\mathcal{P}(X)$.
Conversely, given an ultrafilter $U$ of $\mathcal{P}(X)$, you can define a BA homomorphism $f:\mathcal{P}(X)\to \{\{\emptyset\}, \emptyset\}$ as follows $f(Y)=\{\emptyset\}, \text{ if } Y\in U$ and $f(Y)=\emptyset, \text{ otherwise}.$

$f:\mathcal{P}(X)\to \{\{\emptyset\}, \emptyset\}$ is a boolean algebra homomorphism provided that $f$ preserves $\cap$, $\cup$, $-$, sends $X$ to $\{\emptyset\}$, and sends $\emptyset$ to $\emptyset$.



Relatedly, each ultrafilter of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ corresponds to a congruence of $(\mathcal{P}(X), \cap,\cup, X, \emptyset, -) $ with exactly two equivalence classes.

For example, if $\theta$ is a congruence of $(\mathcal{P}(X), \cap,\cup, X, \emptyset, -) $ with exactly two equivalence classes, then the equivalence class $[X]_\theta$ is an ultrafilter of $\mathcal{P}(X)$.
For the converse, we can use the correspondence between congruences and surjective homomorphism and then use the correspondence between ultrafilters and homomorphisms onto $\{\{\emptyset\}, \emptyset\}$ in (1).

In general, a congruence of a boolean algebra $B$ is an equivalence relation $\theta$ on $B$ that is compatible with the operations of $B$. This means that $x\theta y$ and $x' \theta y'$, then $(x\cap x')\theta (y\cap y')$, $(x\cup x')\theta (y\cup y')$, and $(-x)\theta (-y)$.


$\mathbb R^{X}/\mathcal F$ is a field extending $\mathbb R$ (properly iff $\mathcal F$ is nonprincipal).
